# Swift - Accessing child label text from parent after addSubview

Tags: swift

Hi have an app that adds multiple subviews (UIViews) to the parent using:

```
if let page:UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("recentVC") as? RecentViewController {
   page.view.frame = self.frame
   scrollView.addSubview(page.view)
}
```

In RecentViewController I have a number of elements (labels, image views etc). I would like to set these from the parent view controller. Is this possible and if so any resources?

I have been searching for a while but I can only find info when segues are used.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most the work done for you, create a property in the parent view controller to keep the child view controller.

```
if let page = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("recentVC") as? RecentViewController {
    page.view.frame = self.frame
    self.recentViewController = page
    scrollView.addSubview(page.view)
}
```

Now you can access anything in the child view controller with `self.recentViewController.<childControl>`.

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: When setting up this kind of parent-child relationships, you should use the method from [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

```
if let page = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("recentVC") as? RecentViewController {
    self.recentViewController = page
    self.addChildViewController(page)

    page.view.frame = self.frame
    scrollView.addSubview(page.view)

    page.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

I know this looks mysterious and unnecessary but it will prevent odd nearly untraceable issues in the future.

Oh, and if you ever need to remove the child view

```
self.recentViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
self.recentViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
self.recentViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
```

Comment: Thank you both for you suggestions. This is the one I went with.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using storyboard you can create referencing outlets for views in RecentViewController by dragging them from storyboard to view controller class. Then you can access these properties directly as follow :

```
if let page = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("recentVC") as? RecentViewController {
    page.view.frame = self.frame
    page.someChild.image = someImage // raw example
    self.recentViewController = page
    scrollView.addSubview(page.view)
}
```